# Encrypting identity and password in netctl profile for WPA2 Enterprise

Tags: linux, arch-linux, wifi, netctl, wpa2

Would you please tell me, is it possible to encrypt the `identity` and `password` values in a `netctl` profile configuration file? This profile sets up a connection to a WPA2 Enterprise wireless network. Would you please instruct me on how to encrypt the plain text values, if it is possible?

My current `netctl` profile configuration file is:

```
Description='WiFi'
Interface=wlan0
Connection=wireless
Security=wpa-configsection
IP=dhcp
WPAConfigSection=(
  'ssid="ssid"'
  'proto=WPA RSN'
  'key_mgmt=WPA-EAP'
  'pairwise=CCMP'
  'group=CCMP'
  'eap=PEAP'
  'anonymous_identity="anonymous@domain.name"'
  'identity="USERNAME"'
  'password="PASSWORD"'
  'ca_cert="/path/to/cert.pem"'
  'phase2="auth=MSCHAPV2"'
  'priority=1'
```

)

`USERNAME` and `PASSWORD` in an example above are plain text values. I know it is possible to [obfuscate the wireless passphrase](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Netctl#Obfuscate_wireless_passphrase) when using WPA2-PSK. I'm looking for a similar functionality for WPA2 Enterprise.

Answer (score 1):

I bumped into fipolate some years ago:

[fipolate](https://xyne.dev/projects/fipolate/)

Unfortunately I can't say from personal experience whether this fits the bill.